# Query data, in Redis, by using a field value

Tags: c#, redis, servicestack.redis

Please help me.
I've stored data, in Redis, by using C# servicestack.redis libraries.  In this case, I stored data from 4 classes.  For this case, I want to recover all data, from Redis, by using a value.

[image]

In the image above, it's shown 4 ids, each one is the name of the class that I'm loading, by C#, into Redis.  I want to recover, for CompanyList class (in my program), only data when the value "Expediente" is "100037", but I don't know how or which Redis commands I can use.

In the photo, of course, I've the index value (12381635), but in my program I want to recover all particular data by using "Expediente" and "100037" only.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Redis allows access to data by key, not value. If you need to look up a given value, you'll have to "index" it. See https://redis.io/topics/indexes for guidance.

Comment: Ok.  Is there some example, in c#, in order to implement these kind of indexes?